# Is there a test suite for numpy / scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm about to reinstall `numpy` and `scipy` on my Ubuntu Lucid. As these things carry quite a few dependencies, I'm wondering if there is a comprehensive test suite to check if the new install really works.

Of course, I can just take a bunch of my scripts and run them one by one to see if they keep working, but that won't guard against a situation where at some point in the future I'll try to use something I didn't use before and it'll break (or, worse, silently produce nonsence).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Yes. Both packages have a `test` method for this.

```
import numpy
numpy.test('full')

import scipy
scipy.test('full')
```

You will need to have [pytest](https://pypi.org/project/pytest/) and [hypothesis](https://pypi.org/project/hypothesis/) installed to run `numpy.test`.

Comment: Alternatively you can run the tests on your command line:

```python -c 'import numpy; numpy.test("full");'```

```python -c 'import scipy; scipy.test("full");'```

Comment: it seems that these functions pull in tests from the current directory, so i guess be careful where you call them.

Comment: it's also not a good idea to run `numpy.test` followed by `scipy.test` in the same python session.  i've had issues with `numpy.test` making global changes to variables that are then picked up by `scipy.test`, causing errors in `scipy.test` that wouldn't otherwise occur: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33002730/2623899).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that each return a True/False value instead of failing. So when running it in a shell (`python -c`) you might want to check that or have always an exit code of 0

Answer (score 8):

> Note that binary packages for the mathematical libraries Scipy and
>   Numpy depend on, shipped by Linux distributions, have in some cases
>   showed to be subtly broken. Running Numpy and Scipy test suites with
>   numpy.test() and scipy.test() is recommended, as a first step to
>   confirm that your installation functions properly. If it doesn't, you
>   may want to try another set of binaries if available, or buy some
>   above-mentioned commercial packages.

from http://www.scipy.org/Download