# will recompiling Python require re-install all add-on modules such as numpy, scipy?

Tags: python

I missed out the bz standard moudle during inital python compilation. This version of Python has been in use for a few months and quite a number of add-on modules such as numpy, scipy have been installed since then. Can anyone tell me if I recompile Python, do I have to re-install all add-on modules?
  Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

afaict, no you won't have to reinstall all your modules, if you're only recompiling and `make install`, it will just overwrite already installed files.

Though, if in a recent upgrade you've changed a dependency of python that has been used by a compiled module, then some extensions *may* break. But recompiling only those will make things go fine.

Comment: Yes, you should not have to reinstall.  However, if you are concerned, many modules come with test suites you can run after the fact.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200727/is-there-a-test-suite-for-numpy-scipy]

Comment: Thank you zmo and AFoglia. I will recompile.