# Python: using dictionary value as an index into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array, for example:

```
x = np.zeros((10, 10, 10))
```

Now, I have a dictionary as follows, which keeps a 1-D to 3-D mapping as follows:

```
d = {}
d[0] = (1, 1, 1)
```

Now, I want to access the element referred to by the key, so I tried something like:

```
print x[d[0]]
```

This results in a typeerror as:

```
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am guessing the tuple is not a good idea to store the 3D coordinates. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown us is fine. You have an error somewhere else, probably reusing the `x` or `d` variables or forgetting function call parentheses.

Comment: try: import numpy ; numpy.test('full') here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200727/is-there-a-test-suite-for-numpy-scipy